# Find $x$ such that $x^3+ax+b$ is a square mod $p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Let $p>3$ be a prime, and $a,b \in \Bbb F_p$ such that $4a^3+27b^2 \neq 0$.

Can I find some $x \in \Bbb F_p$ such that $x^3+ax+b$ is a square mod $p$ **without using Hasse's bound**?
I know that $\Bbb F_p$ has $(p+1)/2$ squares (including $0$), but I don't see why $x^3+ax+b$ should take at least one square value.

Comment: So you're asking about the existence of rational (as in $k$-rational where $k = \mathbb{F}_p$) points on an elliptic curve over a finite field? More specifically, the curve, considered in projective space, has always a distinguished rational point at infinity, but you're asking if there must be others, right?

Comment: @SamStreeter : yes, I want a point in the affine space.

Comment: Sorry about my now-deleted answer, I misread the Hasse bound and you were quite right.

Comment: @SamStreeter : no problem! Thank you for having tried :-)

Comment: Would you be satisfied with knowing that there exists an algorithm to produce such nontrivial rational points? If so, see http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.831.5299&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Do you want a proof of existence, or an explicit construction?

Comment: @Servaes : a proof of existence would be fine, provided it doesn't use Hasse bound (if possible). I was just interested in knowing an easy proof for the existence.

Comment: Actually for all smooth projective curves $C$ over $\Bbb Q$, there is $p_0>0$ large enough such that $| C(\Bbb F_p) | > 1$ for $p \geq p_0$, by Weil's bound.